# Does done() accomplish the same thing as catch() in Javascript promises (using sequelize and bluebird)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js, bluebird

I'm trying to make my Express app handle all requests as similarly as possible. I had a server that handled everything with callbacks and the pyramid of doom was terrible. It was also difficult to ensure that I was sending a response for all the calls.

So I'm migrating to a Promise based system (sequelize, which utilizes bluebird's promise library).

I've read that it's best to always follow up with a `.catch(function(err){ report it }` call.

Does `.done()` accomplish the same thing?

My thought (might be naive) is that I can handle all `res.status(x).send(y)` calls in the `.done(success, failure)` functions.

Will `failure` catch everything that `catch()` would? Is it wrong to send all responses in the `done()` function (all success messages in `success` and all failure/error messages in `failure`?

Edit - I'm finding out that `sequelize` uses bluebird's promise library, so `done()` has been depricated for `finally()`. But, `finally()` doesn't take parameters in the functions, so it doesn't seem like I can send all data to `finally()` and handle it there.

Comment: I don't see any `done` function in the docs, but I do see [`then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then). Are you using a Promise library?

Comment: Sequelize. I thought done() was native in promises, that might explain why I couldn't find too much on it.

Comment: I'm not so sure Sequelize has it either. I'm still not finding any `done` function. Are you sure you're not using a library like `Q`? `done` is a non-standard function for Promises. Different libraries implement it differently. Some libraries disregard the `failure`.

Comment: I dug through the source for sequelize and found out it's built on bluebird's promise library. Which means `done()` is depricated and I should use `finally()` instead. I think... (edited the question to reflect this find)

Comment: `finally()` is slightly different. It only has one callback parameter, and it calls it for both `success` or `failure`, just like a normal [`finally {}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) block after a `try/catch`.

Comment: Yea, I'm finding that out as I keep digging. I think I need to handle all successful responses in the corresponding `then()` call, and use `catch()` to handles the errors. I couldn't find the right solution cause I was searching the native promise library when I was actually using bluebird's (unknowingly, I'm new to promises).

Comment: Bluebird is a superset of ES6 standard promises.  You don't show your exact code so we can respond more specifically to your situation, but usually, you will do `someAsyncOperation().then(...).catch(...);`.  This is true in ES6 standard promises or with Bluebird promises.  The `.then()` handles success and the `.catch()` handles error.  You can pass a second handler to `.then()` as the error handler too, but many find it better to use `.catch()` for errors.  `.finally()` is different and the Bluebird docs describe it.  I would avoid `.done()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`done()` is deprecated and I recommend you don't use it - its goal was to throw the rejection as an exception so it propagates. Bluebird keeps track of unresolved promises on its own so `then` does this and warns anyway.

You do *not* want to do `.catch(err => { /* handle */})` unless you actually have the ability to handle the exception - just like `catch (e) {`. If you don't have anything meaningful to do with the exception don't do anything.

In routes for example, you can return a `500` error status if an exception has occured and report something to your tools and to the client.

`finally()` is meant primarily for *resource cleanup* and for making sure you leave everything in a clean state.

Answer (score 1):

Native Promises do not have a `.done()` method. I would recommend sticking with the [ECMAScript spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-promise.prototype.catch) and just using `.then(success).catch(failure)` this will ensure that any error that might get thrown in your `success` function still get caught and handled by your `failure` function.

Comment: I'm using sequelize. I thought done() was native to promises. I was mistaken. I guess the question above is for sequelize and not promises.

Comment: `then` allows for a second function as a parameter for handling the `catch`

Comment: I did some digging and found out `sequelize` is built on bluebird's promise library. So it's a question of `finally()` vs `catch()`. (edited the question to reflect this)

Comment: @4castle yes, but the problem doing that is that any error that might occur in the first parameter passed to `.then()` won't be handled by the second. That's why it's almost always a better idea to just include an additional `.catch()` after `.then()` for catching **all** possible errors.

Comment: @Matt even with bluebird I would still recommend using `.then(success).catch(failure)`.

Comment: `catch` is not in the Promises/A+ spec - oh the irony.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum you are correct, my mistake. I guess I should say, I would recommend sticking with the [ECMAScript specification](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-promise.prototype.catch).

Comment: That would be fine :) Note that the reason native promises don't have a `done` is because it is not needed. `done` was from before we could automatically track unhandled rejections and needed to explicitly terminate promise chains - it was error prone and I strongly recommend against it.

Answer (score 0):

The [`.finally(function() handler) -> Promise`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/finally.html) function is slightly different. It gets invoked for both `success` and `failure`, but notice that it doesn't get any data as a parameter for the `handler`.

It's intended to be used for cleanup, just like a normal `finally` block in a [`try...catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch).

If you need access to the value returned by the Promise, use [`.then()`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/then.html):

```
.then(
    [function(any value) fulfilledHandler],
    [function(any error) rejectedHandler]
) -> Promise
```

Comment: Would it not be better to use `then(success).catch(error)`?

Comment: [`.catch(handler)`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/catch.html) is just a shorthand function for `.then(null, handler)`. If it's more readable to use `catch`, that's fine.

Comment: @Matt it would be, as explained in my answer.